# Getting null pointer exeptcion

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

So can you tell me why  am I getting null pointer exeptcion.
I am checking if asyncTask are over and then getting text from edit text to arryList after that on button click button inovks method myclickhandler1(povijest) and sends intent to secondActivity can you tell me what am I doin wrong here

MainActivity.java

```
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
    private EditText urlText;
    private TextView textView;
    public int numOfTasks = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myurl);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        textView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
          arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();



    }


    public void  myClickHandler(View view) {





        String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {


            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);

        } else {
            textView.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }



     public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {




                try {
                    return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                    addTask();
                    super.onPreExecute();

            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
                textView.setText(result);
                removeTask(); 
                allTasksComplete(); 




           }

        }

     private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;


            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connect.setReadTimeout(10000 );
                connect.setConnectTimeout(15000 );
                connect.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connect.setDoInput(true);
                connect.connect();
                int response = connect.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
                is = connect.getInputStream();


                String contentAsString = readIt(is);
                return contentAsString;


            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                } 
            }
     }


    // Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
     public String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
         if (stream != null) {
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line;

             try {
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     sb.append(line);
                 }
             } finally {
                 stream.close();
             }
             return sb.toString();
         } else {        
             return "";
         }
     }
     public void myClickHandler1(View povijest){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("arry_list", arrayList);
            startActivity(intent);     
           ;

     }

     public void addTask(){
            numOfTasks++;
        }

        public void removeTask(){
            numOfTasks--;
        }

        public void allTasksComplete()
        {

            if(numOfTasks ==0)
                  {

                arrayList.add(urlText.getText().toString());

            }

        }
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package com.example.networking;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);        
        Intent i = getIntent();  
         ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("key");


         lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list );

         lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.networking.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myurl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler1"
        android:text="POVIJEST" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:text="Download" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**second_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.networking.SecondActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which line your getting. post log cat

Comment: ok it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Use `arry_list` instead of `key` to get ArrayList from intent :

```
  ArrayList<String> list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("arry_list");
```

Because in `MainActivity` Activity `arry_list` is used as key to add ArrayList in intent but in `SecondActivity` Activity trying to get ArrayList using `key`.

Comment: Thank you for this a have been strugling with this all day and it was just that simple